# Celery: How to use "link_error" if documentation has an error?

Tags: python, django, celery

In Celery documentation: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains is example how to use `link_error`:

> You can also add error callbacks using the link_error argument:
>
> ```
> add.apply_async((2, 2), link_error=log_error.s())
> add.subtask((2, 2), link_error=log_error.s())
> ```
>
> Since exceptions can only be serialized when pickle is used the error
>   callbacks take the id of the parent task as argument instead:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import print_function 
> import os 
> from proj.celery import app
>
> @app.task 
> def log_error(task_id):
>     result = app.AsyncResult(task_id)
>     result.get(propagate=False)  # make sure result written.
>     with open(os.path.join('/var/errors', task_id), 'a') as fh:
>         print('--\n\n{0} {1} {2}'.format(
>             task_id, result.result, result.traceback), file=fh)
> ```

But in this example is bug because they calling `AsuncResult.get` inside task which causing `DEADLOCK` and this log entries:

```
/opt/.virtualenvs/spark/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/result.py:45: RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task!
See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks

In Celery 3.2 this will result in an exception being
raised instead of just being a warning.

  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(E_WOULDBLOCK))

[2015-06-13 20:30:19,242: WARNING/Worker-4] /opt/.virtualenvs/spark/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/result.py:45: RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task!
See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks

In Celery 3.2 this will result in an exception being
raised instead of just being a warning.

  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(E_WOULDBLOCK))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do this check-list to ensure configuration is ok:

1. `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT` must be set to `False`
2. `CELERY_BACKEND_RESULT` must be set, e.g. `'amqp'` (for RabbitMQ)
3. `@task` decorator **MUST NOT HAVE** option `ignore_result=True` on every task (but You can create [immutable signatures](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/master/userguide/canvas.html#immutability))

The last is properly modified task for fetching result ([allow_join_result](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#synchronous-subtasks)):

```
from celery.result import allow_join_result

@app.task
def log_error(task_id):
    with allow_join_result():
        result = app.AsyncResult(task_id)
        result.get(propagate=False)  # make sure result written.
        with open(os.path.join('/var/errors', task_id), 'a') as fh:
            print('--\n\n{0} {1} {2}'.format(
                task_id, result.result, result.traceback), file=fh)
```

**Note:**
`result.result` in this case of `ZeroDivisionError` is dictionary:

```
{
    'exc_type': 'ZeroDivisionError',  # Name of Exception type
    'exc_message': 'division by zero'  # Reason of exception
}
```

---

### **Note:**

This is [#2652](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2652) issue, when calling `get()` on `AsyncResult` when Celery ignoring error